# Exception when using facebook login in wso2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I had configured a basic authenticator and two Federated authenticators (Google and FB) in wso2 IS 5.1.0. When the user allows the permissions it works fine in FB and Google.But when the user deny for google it redirects properly to the login page.But for FB it throws the following exception and redirects to the retry.do

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.FrameworkException: No authenticator can handle the request in step :  1
```

Comment: What you mean by user deny? Do you mean a failed login attempt?

Comment: No.User needs to allow the app to use OAuth.There if user deny the app then it throws the exception

Comment: Its better to enable debug logs for authentication framework and oAuth2 module. It will be helpful to understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think FacebookAuthenticator doesn't handle error when user doesn't give permission to apps to access the facebook account

```
diff --git a/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/social/facebook/FacebookAuthenticator.java b/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/social/facebook/FacebookAuthenticator.java
index 780e732..cd62cf6 100644
--- a/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/social/facebook/FacebookAuthenticator.java
+++ b/components/application-authenticators/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.social/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authenticator/social/facebook/FacebookAuthenticator.java
@@ -138,6 +138,10 @@ public class FacebookAuthenticator extends AbstractApplicationAuthenticator impl
                 request.getParameter(FacebookAuthenticatorConstants.OAUTH2_PARAM_STATE) != null &&
                 FacebookAuthenticatorConstants.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_TYPE.equals(getLoginType(request))) {
             return true;
+        } else if (request.getParameter(FacebookAuthenticatorConstants.OAUTH2_PARAM_STATE) != null &&
+            request.getParameter("error") != null) {
+               //if sends error like access_denied
+               return true;
         }

         return false;
```